# CSS: On hover display block not working

Tags: html, css, html-lists, onhover

For following html on hovering li.visibleLi li.invisibleLi need to be shown.

```
<ul>
  <li class="visibleLi">Web Design</li>
  <li class="invisibleLi">Web Development</li>
  <li class="invisibleLi">Illustrations</li>
</ul>
```

I tried the following css:

```
li.invisibleLi { display: none; }
li.visibleLi:hover li.invisibleLi{ display: block; }
```

But it is not working.. Can anyone please correct me?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You try like this-

```css
    ul li.invisibleLi { display: none; }
    ul li.visibleLi:hover ~ li.invisibleLi{ display: block; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="visibleLi">Web Design</li>
  <li class="invisibleLi">Web Development</li>
  <li class="invisibleLi">Illustrations</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it will helps you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hover over something that is not displayed. You could use opacity or visibility instead.

```
li.invisibleLi { opacity: 0 }
ul li.visibleLi:hover ~ li.invisibleLi{ opacity: 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The space between elements looks for children. Try a comma instead of just a space.

Comment: Instead of seperating by a space you should also add a comma: `li.visibleLi:hover, li.invisibleLi{ display: block; }`

Comment: When i add comma, all li are visible onload itself.